# Find the basis of the subspace of polynomial space.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> **Question**: given $$W=\{p(x)\in K[x] : x^2 p''(x)-4xp'(x)+6p(x)=0\}$$
>
> show that $W$ is finite dimensional subspace of $K[x]$ and verify that $2x^2+3x^3\in W$ and find basis of $W$ which contains  $2x^2+ 3x^3$ where $K$ is field and $p'(x), p''(x)$ denotes the first order and second order derivatives of $p(x)$ respectively.

**My attempt**: I can easily show $W$ is subspace of $K[x]$. Clearly zero polynomial is in $W$ and $W⊆K[x]$ and it is easy to see that, $p(x)+q(x)\in W$ and $k p(x)\in W$ for every $p(x),q(x)\in W$ and for all $k\in K$.Hence $W$ is subspace of $K[x]$.

**But, how can I prove $W$ is finite dimensional subspace of $K[x]$? How to find basis of $W$?**

Please help me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since differation is linear operator the set $W$ is closed for sum and multiplying with constant, i.e. it is a subspace.

Let $p(x)=a x^n+...$, where $a\ne 0$ be a solution of this equation, so $p\in W$. Since $$p'(x)= a\cdot n\cdot x^{n-1}+...$$ and $$ p''(x) = a\cdot n\cdot (n-1)x^{n-2}+...$$ then, if we compare the coefficents at the higest degree, we have $$n(n-1)-4n+6=0$$

so $$n^2-5n+6=0\implies n\in\{2,3\}$$

So your set $W$ contains polynomials of the degree $2$ and $3$.

So if $p(x) = ax^3+bx^2+cx+d\in W$ and $a\ne 0$ we get $$2cx+6d=0\implies c=d=0$$
so all polynomials of form $ax^3+bx^2$ are in $W$

and if $p(x) = ax^2+bx+c\in W$ and $a\ne 0$ we get $$ 2bx+6c =0\implies b=c=0$$
so all polynomials of form $ax^2$ are in $W$.

So we can take the basis of $W$ the set $\{x^2,x^3\}$.

---

Specificaly, let $q(x)=2x^2+3x^3$ then we have $q'(x)=4x+9x^2$ and $q''(x)=4+18x$, so $$x^2 q''(x)-4xq'(x)+6q(x)= 4x^2+18x^3-16x^2-36x^3+12x^2+18x^3 =0$$

we see $q\in W$.

Comment: Sir/mam, really I didn't get how you get $n(n-1)-4n+6=0$ ? How you conclude that only degree 2 and degree 3 polynomial are in $W$. Please could you elaborate(upper part of your solution)

Comment: Thank you so much sir/mam. Very beautiful answer and nice explanation.